# Can we fix the grammar in our tag for 'time-constrain'?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I was running through the review queue, and noticed a suggestion for information about the [time-constrain](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-constrain) tag.

Could we edit this tag to read 'time-constraint'? 'Constrain' is a verb; 'constraint' is the noun we are looking for. Given that we are a writing site, I figured proper grammar is something we should strive for in our tags. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This turned out to be the tip of a larger iceberg.

We had two messages tagged "time-constrain" (sic).  We had a bunch of questions tagged "time", which were divided between questions about *managing* time and questions about *depicting time in written works*.  That's confusing, so I split "time" into [time-management](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-management) and [time-depiction](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-depiction), retagged a few questions, and eliminated the "time-constrain" tag in the process.

I also wrote a short wiki for what was time (now time-depiction) and updated the wiki for time-management to add cross-references.

Comment: Good work Monica. Thanks!